# Chromium webrowser can't be installed in tinycore 5.3.19

Tags: chrome, browser, application, tinycore

I'm working with tinycore-5.3.19 in an x86 architecture. I've tried to install a browser using the Apps. Browser. I've selected as remote extension `chromium-browser.tcz`. "OnBoot":

Details:

- Title: chrmoimum-browser.tcz
- version: 23.0.1271.64
- original-site::http://code.google.com/chromium/
- size:44m

But it fails to install. The status message is:

> chromium-broser.tcz Failed.

No more Info to guess which is the problem.

#### Questions

- Has anyone tried to install this extension?
- Someone could, please, tell me which may be the problem?

#### EDIT #1: New information

If I try to install it in tinycorelinux 3.8.4, `chromium-browser.tcz` tries to install, but it gives me this error:

> mount: mounting /dev/loop5 on /tmp/tcploop/glib2 failed: invalid argument.

And if I try to install and download `glib2.tcz` the new error is:

> Error in glib2.tcz

**EDIT #2: 
New information**

I've been suggested to better follow this tutorial:
http://distro.ibiblio.org/tinycorelinux/book.html
Maybe it's useful for anybody else in trouble with tinycore.
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I didn't have enough space in tce directory.
After changing my partition size I downloaded and install chromium-browser.tcz correctly.

Command to download the extension:

```
   $tce-load -wi chromium-browser
```

Regards